# Manipulating an object through its reference

Tags: java, reference

I'm coding an implementation of HashTable as an exercise in my course, I'm using an array of LinkedLists, each containing a key-value pair (Element), to achieve this.
Instead of writing `list[key % size]` to reference the element I'm manipulating, I want to write `currentNode`.

This code throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
public void put(int key, T value) {
        var currentNode = list[key % size];

        if(currentNode == null)
            list[key % size] = new LinkedList<>();
        else
            for(var item : currentNode)
                if (item.value == value)
                    return;
        currentNode.add(new Element<>(key, value));
    }
```

I understand the error occurs because `currentNode` is holding a reference to a null object, my question is why isn't `currentNode` updated when `list[key % size]` is updated?

Comment: `currentNode` and `list[key % size]` are not the same memory location themselves, but they can each store a copy of the same Reference

Comment: @xtratic I see. Is there a way to make ```currentNode``` not store a copy of the reference and actually refer to ```list[key % size]```, so it changes along with it?

Comment: In Java.. no, since you don't get control over memory addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...my question is why isn't currentNode updated when list[key % size]
> is updated?

Because `currentNode` is not an alias for `list[key % size]`.  The element in the `list` array and `currentNode` are each *separate* variables both of which contain the same reference after this statement is executed:

```
var currentNode = list[key % size];
```

When these statements execute and the predicate evaluates to `true`:

```
if(currentNode == null)
            list[key % size] = new LinkedList<>();
```

The variable at array location `[key % size]` will contain a reference to the newly created linked list instance.  However `currentNode` will still contain `null`, as its reference was not updated by the assignment.

To force both these variables to have the same reference to the same instance, you'll want to do something like this:

```
if(currentNode == null)
            currentNode = new LinkedList<>();
            list[key % size] = currentNode;
:
:
```

As a performance aside, the `%` operator is a somewhat expensive operation.  If you expect `put()` operations on your tables to frequently result in new list entries, it would perhaps be more performant (and definitely more readable) to hoist the operation up to an assignment at the beginning of your method:

```
public void put(int key, T value) {
        int index = key % size;
        var currentNode = list[index];
```

and then replace all occurrences of `key % size` with `index`.

Comment: Thank you very much(:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this schema will help you:

```
  Reference          Heap Object
```

Moment 1: current node     ->   object 1 (null)

```
  list[key % size]     ->
```

Moment 2: current node     ->   object 1 (null)

```
  list[key % size]     ->   object 2(new LinkedList<>();)
```